# How to implement search controller for both iOS 7 & iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

i'm targeting my app should run on both iOS 7 & iOS 8. Since UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8, i used UISearchController for iOS 8. But it's not working in iOS 7. If i use UISearchDisplayController then it will work in iOS 7. But what is best way to implement the search controller for both platform ? In iOS 8, i implemented search controller like below -

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Search Controller Setup
            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "ব্র্যান্ড/সংস্থা/দোকান খুঁজুন"

            // Make sure the that the search bar is visible within the navigation bar.
            searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
            definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

and for iOS 7 in SWIFT, how can i implement UISearchDisplayController programatically like above to make sure that search bar is visible within the navigation bar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ios7 way. Even if it deprecates.
Or you will have to make two code, one for handle iOS7 and the other one for iOS8.
IF you are targetting iOS 7, Xcode won't show you warnings.

Comment: how can i implement UISearchDisplayController programatically like i did for iOS 8. I tried searchController = UISearchDisplayController(searchResultsController: nil)  instead of UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil). But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

// Change the appearance of the search Bar

```
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 235.0/255.0, green: 73.0/255.0, blue: 27.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Something"
    searchController.searchBar.prompt = "Quick Search"
```

//   Make searchBar appear in the navigation Bar

```
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

// You dont need to set the delegate to self, instead

```
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // important
```

After this, you need to adhere to the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol and implement,

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
```

which will contain the logic of your search.